# Passing a hiddenfield form value to a Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, controller, getjson, formcollection

I have a jQuery getJson method which correctly returns a selected CustomerID. When that happens, a button is enabled to send the CustomerID to another Controller method which would then open up a form to modify the customer.

I check the Form collection, but there is no value associated with the ID of the Collection. It simply comes out as "CustomerID" with no value.

How can I successfully pass this value to the other Controller with the Form Collection?

I know that the script section contains the var CustomerID and the BeginForm has the hiddenfield value, but obviously, there is no "linkage" between the two. I'm wondering how I can do this...

So basically, how can I get the JS variable value inside CustomerID into the Form?

### JS

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function ()
        {
            var selID = null;
            var CustomerID = null;
            $("#Name").change(function ()
            {
                selID = $("#Name option:selected").val();

                var url = '/Project/SpecificCustomer';
                var param = { Id: selID };
                $.getJSON(url, param, function (data)
                {
                    var html = "<table border='1' cellpadding='3'>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + "Customer ID: " + data.CustomerID + "</td>";
                    CustomerID = data.CustomerID;
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + "Email: " + data.Email + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    var FirstName = data.FirstName;
                    FirstName == null ? "" : FirstName;
                    var LastName = data.LastName;
                    LastName == null ? "" : LastName;
                    html += "<td>" + "Name: " + FirstName + " " + LastName + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    var date1 = new Date(parseInt(data.CreatedDate.substr(6)));
                    date1 == null ? "" : date1;
                    html += "<td>" + "Created: " + date1 + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    var date2 = new Date(parseInt(data.UpdatedDate.substr(6)));
                    date2 == null ? "" : date2;
                    html += "<td>" + "Updated: " + date2 + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "</table>";
                    $("#divData").html('');
                    $("#divData").append(html);

                    if (CustomerID != null)
                        $("#UpdateCust").prop('disabled', false);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customer", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Customer</legend>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="hidden" id="custID" name="custID" value="CustomerID" />
            <input type="submit" id="UpdateCust" value='@Resources.Update' disabled="disabled" />
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

### Other Controller method

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
        {
            string custID = form["custID"];
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear, but if the form resides on the same page as the `getJSON` script, then you could change the last lines of your JavaScript to be:

```
if (CustomerID != null) {
          $("#UpdateCust").prop('disabled', false);
          $("#custID").val(data.CustomerID);
}
```

Comment: Wow... That worked great and showed me a different technique that I wasn't thinking of or else I would have had to put it in session state. Thanks a lot!